# Why is `std::string_view` not implemented differently?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

Given the following code we can see that `std::string_view` is invalidated when string grows beyond capacity (here SSO is in effect initially then contents are put on the heap)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::string s = "hi";
    std::string_view v = s;

    cout << v << endl;

    s = "this is a long long long string now";

    cout << v << endl;
}
```

output:

```
hi
#
```

so if I store a string_view to a string then change the contents of the string I can be in big trouble.
Would it be possible, given the existing `std::string` implementations to make a smarter `string_view`? which would not face such a drawback? We could store a pointer to the string object itself and then determine if the string is in SSO more or not and work accordingly.(Not sure how this would work with literal strings though, so maybe that is why it was not done this way?)

I am aware that `string_view` is akin to storing the return value of `string::c_str()` but given we have this wrapper around `std::string` I do not think this gotcha would occur to a lot of people using this feature.  Most disclaimers are to make sure the pointed to `std::string` is within scope but this is a different issue altogether.

Comment: `std::string const &` already exists.

Comment: "*given we have this wrapper around std::string*" That's not what `string_view` is.

Comment: @user3840170 hmm now I feel I over thought about this.... :(

Comment: You could write a `string_view` like class that would survive changes to the string except when the string shrinks too much. There is no way to keep a view of the string from char 10-20 alive when you shrink the string to 5 chars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string_view` knows nothing about `string`. It is not a "wrapper" around a `string`. It has no idea that `std::string` *even exists* as a type; the conversion from `string` to `string_view` happens within `std::string`. `string_view` has no association with or reliance on `std::string`.

In fact, that is the *entire purpose* of `string_view`: to be able to have a non-modifiable sized string without knowing how it is allocated or managed. That it can reference any string type that stores its characters contiguously is the point of the thing. It allows you to create an interface that takes a `string_view` without knowing or caring whether the caller is using `std::string`, `CString`, or any other string type.

Since the owning string's behavior is not `string_view`'s business, there is no possible mechanism for `string_view` to be told when the string it references is no longer valid.

---

> We could store a pointer to the string object itself and then determine if the string is in SSO more or not and work accordingly.

For the sake of argument, let us ignore that `string_view` is not supposed to know or care whether its characters come from `std::string`. Let's assume that `string_view` only works with `std::string` (even though that makes the type completely worthless).

Even then, this would not work. Or rather, it would only work if the type was functionally no different from a `std::string const&`.

If `string_view` stores a pointer to the first character and a size, then any modification to the `std::string` might change this. It could change the size even without breaking small-string optimization. It could change the size without causing reallocation. The only way to correct this is to have the `string_view` always ask the `std::string` it references what its character data and size are.

And that's no different from just using a `std::string const&` directly.

Comment: I see, I don't think I understood the spirit of `string_view` but your answer clears it up. What threw me off is that resizing of the string will also affect `string_view` which is not mentioned often, usually what is mentioned is that `std::string` must be alive so I got curious, I guess it is not tied closely with `std::string` or anything else so makes sense

Comment: @PYA it makes more sense if you think of `std::string` as a container of `char`. Modifying containers in general risks invalidating pointers into to their contents, and `string_view` is essentially a pointer

Comment: A `std::string` only `string_view` would not store a pointer to the first `char` but rather have `struct { std::string &str; std::size_t begin; std::size_t end; }` and would remain valid as long as the string size does not shrink below end. How would you replace this with `std::string const&`? The `substr` method would copy the string while it runs in `O(1)` for `string_view`.